# Create unique files in loop

Tags: vb.net

Im looking for a way to create unique files in a loop, meaning that I want them to have different names for each time if loops. Im writing something that finds some values from a html and does that in a loop. It doesnt matter what the file is called since its deleted shortly after (just a temporary file to store two lines) but they have to be saved in the same directory. Can I create a sort of array for the files? I have a feeling that its quite easy but I just can't see it at the moment.

Hope you can help me.

Cheers, 
Snoop

Comment: Why not just name them 1, 2, 3, ... or use the current datetime as a convention for naming, then???

Comment: Look at the [GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Well how do I express that in a loop? If It's a normal string that no promblem but I have no idea how to do that becasue I always need the same directory

Comment: @SnoopCn You never said it had to be created in a specific folder. Please edit your question to include that as a requirement.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't matter at all you could use a `Guid`:

```
Dim directory = "Folder-Path"
Dim fileName = String.Format("{0}.txt", Guid.NewGuid())
Dim fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, fileName)
```